# How to make backpack parented to bone to be detachable with good weight paint for straps?

Tags: animation, armature, bones, weight-painting, rigify

I have one backpack object paranted to armature like this (it needs to be detachable to be able to fall down, etc) with Child Of constraint to follow the chest bone of the character:

### [image: backpack1]

But that creates some problems because my straps have 100% weight of this bone also. Straps now don't follow the topology of character:

[image: backpack2]

If I weight paint straps (directly to the chest bone for example) to fix that, backpack will not be detachable anymore:

[image]

Is there a way to fix that without separating the mesh of backpack or creating additional bones for it? Thanks!